# Remove an object in nesting array of objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm having an array with nesting array and object as below. Now, with specific id, how can I remove an object and it's children ?

lets say I want to remove an object whose id is 30. So the final out will be the array which will not have object containing id=30

```
let data= [{"name": "Corporate","id": 1,"editMode": true,"children": [{"name": "Banner","id": 2,"parentId": 1,"editMode": true,"children": [{"name": "Division","id": 3,"parentId": 2,"editMode": false,"children": [{"name": "Region","id": 4,"editMode": true,"children": [{"name": "District","id": 5,"editMode": true,"children": [{"name": "Store","id": 6,"editMode": false,"children": []}]}]}]},{"name": "Banner1","id": 30,"editMode": true,"children": [{"name": "Banner11","id": 35,"editMode": true,"children": []}]},{"name": "Banner1","id": 31,"editMode": true,"children": []},{"name": "Banner1","id": 32,"editMode": true,"children": [{"name": "Banner11","id": 33,"editMode": true,"children": []},{"name": "Banner11","id": 34,"editMode": true,"children": []}]}]},{"name": "Corporate1","id": 36,"editMode": true,"children": [{"name": "Corporate11","id": 38,"editMode": true,"children": []},{"name": "Corporate11","id": 39,"editMode": true,"children": []}]},{"name": "Corporate1","id": 37,"editMode": true,"children": []}]}];
```

In the below snipped I was able to get the nested object, But how can I delete it from the array?

```js
let data= [{"name": "Corporate","id": 1,"editMode": true,"children": [{"name": "Banner","id": 2,"parentId": 1,"editMode": true,"children": [{"name": "Division","id": 3,"parentId": 2,"editMode": false,"children": [{"name": "Region","id": 4,"editMode": true,"children": [{"name": "District","id": 5,"editMode": true,"children": [{"name": "Store","id": 6,"editMode": false,"children": []}]}]}]},{"name": "Banner1","id": 30,"editMode": true,"children": [{"name": "Banner11","id": 35,"editMode": true,"children": []}]},{"name": "Banner1","id": 31,"editMode": true,"children": []},{"name": "Banner1","id": 32,"editMode": true,"children": [{"name": "Banner11","id": 33,"editMode": true,"children": []},{"name": "Banner11","id": 34,"editMode": true,"children": []}]}]},{"name": "Corporate1","id": 36,"editMode": true,"children": [{"name": "Corporate11","id": 38,"editMode": true,"children": []},{"name": "Corporate11","id": 39,"editMode": true,"children": []}]},{"name": "Corporate1","id": 37,"editMode": true,"children": []}]}];
console.log(findNestedObj(data, 'id', 30));

function findNestedObj(entireObj, keyToFind, valToFind) {
  let foundObj;
  JSON.stringify(entireObj, (_, nestedValue) => {
    if (nestedValue && nestedValue[keyToFind] === valToFind) {
      foundObj = nestedValue;
    }
    return nestedValue;
  });
  return foundObj;
};
```

Comment: Get familiar with [how to access and process objects and arrays](/q/11922383/4642212), and use the static and instance methods of [`Object`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Static_methods) and [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods). Then, [edit] your question and provide a [mre] along with your _desired_ results, your _actual_ results, and demonstrate _your research and your attempts_ and explain what precisely didn’t work. Where in the process of writing your code are you stuck?

Comment: @SebastianSimon edited it with my try, but i'm not able to delete that object

Comment: Strange, in your desired output there is still the object with id 30. Also your code seems to be some attempt to *find* an object, not to *remove* it. Are you looking to find it?

Comment: @trincot I tried to remove that object, but was not able to do that. Tried reverse engineering so I made a try to find that object in the nesting array of objects. now I want to delete that from my original array

Comment: If you tried to remove that object, and not able to, then it would be appropriate that you would include the code of *that* attempt. In your current code there is no trace of an attempt to remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution where you pass a callback function -- much like the native `Array#filter` takes a callback -- which expresses what you want to *keep* instead of what you want to *remove*.

It first filters the given array with the native method, and then repeats it recursively for any `children` arrays, creating new objects with the newly filtered arrays that come back from such recursive calls:

```js
function filterObjectArray(arr, filter) {
  return arr.filter(filter).map(obj => obj.children ? {
    ...obj,
    children: filterObjectArray(obj.children, filter)
  } : obj);
};

let data= [{"name": "Corporate","id": 1,"editMode": true,"children": [{"name": "Banner","id": 2,"parentId": 1,"editMode": true,"children": [{"name": "Division","id": 3,"parentId": 2,"editMode": false,"children": [{"name": "Region","id": 4,"editMode": true,"children": [{"name": "District","id": 5,"editMode": true,"children": [{"name": "Store","id": 6,"editMode": false,"children": []}]}]}]},{"name": "Banner1","id": 30,"editMode": true,"children": [{"name": "Banner11","id": 35,"editMode": true,"children": []}]},{"name": "Banner1","id": 31,"editMode": true,"children": []},{"name": "Banner1","id": 32,"editMode": true,"children": [{"name": "Banner11","id": 33,"editMode": true,"children": []},{"name": "Banner11","id": 34,"editMode": true,"children": []}]}]},{"name": "Corporate1","id": 36,"editMode": true,"children": [{"name": "Corporate11","id": 38,"editMode": true,"children": []},{"name": "Corporate11","id": 39,"editMode": true,"children": []}]},{"name": "Corporate1","id": 37,"editMode": true,"children": []}]}];

console.log(filterObjectArray(data, obj => obj?.id !== 30));
```